# Inject variable value in lldb command

Tags: lldb

Is it possible to do that with lldb:

```
(lldb) p my_var
(uint64_t) $9 = 2
(lldb) set set target.max-children-count 4
```

But instead of 4, I would like to call the set command with the current value of `my_var`, in this case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most lldb commands, backtick blocks are evaluated and the result substituted in their place.  For instance,

```
(lldb) sett show stop-line-count-before
stop-line-count-before (int) = 3
(lldb) p 5
(int) $1 = 5
(lldb) sett set stop-line-count-before `$1`
(lldb) sett show stop-line-count-before
stop-line-count-before (int) = 5
```